# How to get culprits or committers inside a Jenkins workflow with one or more SCMs

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to access information about committers and/or culprits of a Jenkins workflow job when checking out from one or more SCMs (either via checkout() or other SCM steps like git/svn)?

The intention is to use that information to notify committers and/or culprits about the job status, for example in a `mail` step.

A small example of a workflow definition:

```
node {
  // checkout from one or more SCMs, e.g.
  git url: '<URL>' 
  checkout([$class:...])
  ...

  // how can we know about committers or culprits at this point?
  $committers = ??

  // send a mail to committers or culprits
  mail to: '$committers', subject: 'JENKINS', body: '<information about the job status>'
}
```

How could this be adapted to get a collection of the committers after running the SCM steps?

Edit:
I am currently working with Jenkins version 1.596.2 and Workflow: Aggregator version 1.6 and it seems this is an open issue in  [JENKINS-24141](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24141)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? This seems like a real deal breaker for migrating to pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, pending [JENKINS-24141](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24141) this is not supported. Changes to Jenkins core are required.

Comment: If it is not possible to get a list of committers from within the workflow, is it possible to write a plugin step to do this?  And how would I get started in writing such a plugin step?

Comment: It seems the ticket in question was fixed. Anybody has any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Jesse, the issue you linked to was recently resolved.  Any chance you could update your answer to show how to get the committers with a recent version of the pipeline/workflow plugin?

Answer (score 11):

This is now possible using the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin.

```
def to = emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
                             [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
                             [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']])
if (to != null && !to.isEmpty()) {
    mail to: to, subject: "JENKINS", body: "See ${env.BUILD_URL}"
}
```

However, if you just want to send an email on failures, you may want to use Mailer (based on the [email-ext pipeline examples](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-PipelineExamples)):

```
step([$class: 'Mailer',
      notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
      recipients: emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
                                      [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']])])
```

Comment: You second example (`step(...)`) works for me, but strangely it doesn't use the _Default Content_ configured at https://<JENKINSURL>/configure

The mail I receive starts with _See_ followed by the link to the blue ocean build. I was expecting the build to the classic version.

Ideas?

Comment: @firepol I believe Jenkins plugins can override the build URL. I know Blue Ocean has [integrated with the new Display URL API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/BlueOcean+Display+URL+Plugin) recently.

Answer (score 7):

Using groovy within a pipeline script:

```
@NonCPS  // Necessary to allow .each to work.
def changelist() {
    def changes = ""
    currentBuild.changeSets.each { set ->
        set.each { entry ->
            changes += "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author.fullName}\n"
        }
    }
    changes
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `@NonCPS` instead of `@NoCPS` ?!

Answer (score 5):

similar to the answer from @szym, but without the `@NonCPS` required:

`def authors = currentBuild.changeSets.collectMany { it.toList().collect { it.author } }.unique()`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the xml info for a job in which you will find the name of the person who committed the change along with the commit messages.

```
http://<Jenkins URL>:<Port Number>/job/<Jobname>/<BuildNumber>/api/xml?
```

Give this a go in your browser. Search for "user".
You can dump this information in a text file to process.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this feature was implemented inside the email-ext plugin but the author forgot to document the way we are supposed to use this.

Please check https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34763 -- and add a comment there, asking for an example. I already did.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch committers email :

```
committerEmail = sh (
  script: 'git --no-pager show -s --format=\'%ae\'',
  returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

and send:

```
emailext body: 'text you choose', subject: 'subject you choose', recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']], to: committerEmail
```

taken from : https://medium.com/@dilunika/find-the-git-commit-user-jenkins-pipeline-b6790613f8b5

Answer (score 0):

In the `emailext` plugin you can provide *culprits*, *developers*, *requestor* etc in the `recipientProviders` directly.

```
emailext body: '', 
recipientProviders: [culprits(),
 developers(),
 brokenBuildSuspects(), 
 brokenTestsSuspects(), 
 requestor()], 
subject: ''
```

**Description**

**Culprits:** Sends email to the list of users who committed a change since the last non-broken build till now. This list at least always include people who made changes in this build, but if the previous build was a failure it also includes the culprit list from there.

**Developers:**  Sends email to all the people who caused a change in the change set.

**Broken Build suspects:**  Sends email to the list of users suspected of causing the build to begin failing.

**Broken Test suspects**:  Sends email to the list of users suspected of causing a unit test to begin failing. This list includes committers and requestors of the build where the test began to fail, and those for any consecutive failed builds prior to the build in which the test began to fail.

*Source:* Jenkins Pipeline Syntax - Snippet Generator

Answer (score -2):

If you want to notify the culprits who broke the build, You do not need to any checks, Use email plugin in jenkins. This plugin gives you option to send mails to commiter between past good build and current broken build.

If you are using "Editable email notifier plugin" You get option of send mail to culprit.

If you are using email plugin then you get the option "Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build".

Comment: Hi, thanks for yor reply. To clarify: I was using freestyle jobs with the editable email notifier plugin. Now I am switching to workflow jobs, where I currently don't see any option to include this functionality. The only option I see is the regular mail step where I can specify the receiver(s) of an email. Here I would like to be able to send to the committers that broke the build. Do you know whether this is possible?